# How does writing/reading multiple values to/from a unbuffered channel work in Go?

Tags: go, goroutine

This seems to challenge my understanding of unbuffered channel, which is that it can only take one value and then it would block for a reader to read it.

1. How in the following code `writeToChan` is able to write 3 values?
2. More so surprisingly, how are those values available to be read later albeit not in same order?

An excerpt from https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#channels

> Receivers always block until there is data to receive. If the channel is unbuffered, the sender blocks until the receiver has received the value. If the channel has a buffer, the sender blocks only until the value has been copied to the buffer; if the buffer is full, this means waiting until some receiver has retrieved a value.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    ch := make(chan int)

    go writeToChan(ch)
    go rdFrmChan(ch)
    
    x := <- ch
    fmt.Println("main read 1 -:",x)
    fmt.Println("main read 2 -:",<-ch)
}

func writeToChan(c chan int) {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    c <- 42
    c <- 27
    c <- 9
}

func rdFrmChan(c chan int) {
    fmt.Println("Go routine read :", <-c)
}
```

Output:

```
Go routine read : 27<br>
main read 1 -: 42<br>
main read 2 -: 9<br>
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/DYzfYh-kXnC

Comment: The program can send three values to the channel because the program receives three values from the channel.   Each communication waits for a sender and a receiver to be ready.

Comment: @gopher Actually not true. Even if I comment following two lines it works. `//x := <- ch
 //fmt.Println("main read 1 -:",x)` It just ignores third value.

Comment: @JimB That's the whole point. In above program it seems to store values!!

Comment: Sorry, I don’t see how you can come to that conclusion. Each goroutine can send exactly when the value can be received.

Comment: @jimb The goroutine `writeToChan` is executed once but it is sending three values on a unbuffered channel. It has not been executed three times.

Comment: See this version of the program that waits for all goroutines to complete: https://play.golang.org/p/fMVw6UUad5R.   The program deadlocks when the receive to variable `x` is commented out.   Observe that `writeToChan` deadlocks earlier when more receive operations are commented out.  The goroutine `writeToChan` does not complete until all three values are received.

Comment: @gopher I understand that there are ways around the issue. WaitGroups or Mutex. Point I am trying to make/clarify is that nothing is preventing a go routine to write to a channel multiple times when in the docs they say it can only hold one value.

Comment: @Mayank The unbuffered  channel holds no values. The send operations in `writeToChan`  wait for a receiver to be ready.   There must be three receive operations on the channel for `writeToChan` to send three values.  If the program does not receive three times, then `writeToChan` blocks.  I added the WaitGroup to illustrate where the program blocks.  It's not some kind of workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each line of the excerpt pasted is proven by your example code, if you understand the sequence of events happening.

1. After the goroutines are started, your main routine is blocked reading from the channel `c`, as it is yet to see a value to read. The `writeToChan` routine waits for a second before writing the first value to the channel
2. The goroutine `rdFrmChan` is also blocked, because it is waiting to read on the channel `ch`
3. After 1s, when the sleep on `writeToChan` expires, the first write (`c <- 42`) will unblock your main routine first, causing the value to be stored in `x` i.e. 42
4. Next the `rdFrmChan` is unblocked on the next write to the channel (`c <- 27`) and sees the value 27. The routine terminates at this point after printing the value
5. At this point, there is only value to be written and one to be read. The third write (`c <- 9`) from the goroutine allows the main routine to read the value as part of `<-ch` and print it

Comment: Thanks for not giving up on me! I was obviously was reading the program as if all the writes to channel are executing together since they are in goroutine. This helps. Also added step by step here https://play.golang.org/p/-tntTSUG8Yw Might help someone else who is new to channels and goroutine.